# Struts 1 excludePattern for use webservice

Tags: web-services, struts1

I am trying to implement a webservice in a Struts1 web application, but Struts intercept all actions.
¿Is any way to exclude specific paths as excludePattern in Struts2?

Comment: You mean a non-Struts 1 web service? There are multiple ways this could be implemented; if you don't want to namespace all of your S1 actions you could just define your servlet mappings in order and give your web service(s) a namespace, you could extend/replace the default S1 servlet, you could customize a request processor, you could (ab)use a filter, etc.

Comment: Finally I used jersey following this tutorial :) https://www.java4s.com/web-services/jersey-hello-world-example-using-jax-rs-specification/